# is it possible to place select menu and input type in a same line?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to place select menu and input type in a same line.

This is the link to jsfiddle  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DRs8p/).

### html

```
<div class="lin">
<select data-inline="true">
<option>1</option>
<option>hello</option>
</select>
```

I tried it using style but i didn't get please any one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place it in a grid, jQuery Mobile has available **[solution](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html)**.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/26uph/

#### HTML:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text"/></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <select data-inline="true">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>hello</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <input type="text" name="txt" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
    display:inline;
    float: left
    }
.right{
    float:right;  
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/DRs8p/3/